# Is it possible to make a jar file using Selenium java and Eclipse and run that file on any machine for the testing

Tags: automated-testing, java

I am using Selenium and Java with Eclipse and TestNG.

Now I want to make a *.jar* file for running this test case on another system that doesn't have Selenium and Java.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can run TestNG programatically (more details [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically)):

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Run2.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

And together with the [Eclipse Export Wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-33.htm), you can create an executable for it.

> that don't have ... Java setup

But naturally you need a JRE to execute *.jar*

However, if you simply [boot up a container with Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images), you will be able to manage changes extremely more easily than with executable files. More details [here](https://robotninja.com/blog/introduction-using-selenium-docker-containers-end-end-testing/).

Comment: Obviously you will need Docker installed to run contain er. What's the advantage over installing JRE?